# How should I separate these strings in the shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to get the size of a `file`. When I use the `file_size=$(du -sh filepath)` command, the value of file_size is: `209715200       mix1-perceptron-large-no-sms-lru-4core_10M.txt`

So I want to separate the strings and only get the size value of the file.

I tried:

```
1.  file_size=$(du -sh filepath | tr -c -d [:digit:] )
```

But the number in the file path will also be retained.

```
2. file_size=$(du -sh filepath | cut -d " " -f1 )
```

But `cut` does not seem to be able to use "space as a separator."

If I use

```
  3. file_size=$(du -sh filepath | cut -d "/" -f1 )
```

This seems to be possible. But when `file_path` does not start with /. This doesn't seem to work either. Is there a general method?

Comment: Do you want to specifically separate strings or do you want to get size of a path in bytes? is it XY question?

Comment: I want to get the size of the file, but how do I make it separate?

Comment: Why do you use `cut -d /` , when the filename is not separated by a slash from the size value?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `cut` did not work is that the output of `du` contains a tab, not a space, after the size. Simply remove the `-d " "` option, leaving the delimiter as its default of tab.

Answer (score 1):

Used awk to select the first column since there is only line -

```sh
file_size=$(du -sh filepath | awk '{print $1}')
```